# Swift - 2 DatePickers

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, keyboard

I have 2 date picker connected to 2 different text fields, both implemented in a singe page and both have the same code (almost, apart of some var inside the code to collect the data). 
The first one is working like a charm. But the issue is when tapping in the second text fields, the standard text keyboard shows up, I added a code to dismiss the keyboard (to dismiss a actual keyboard from another text field) when I tap out of the text field, so this keyboard is dismissed.
The thing gets weirder when I tap inside the text field again the date picker pops up.
The code for the first date picker:

```
@IBAction func CallPicker(sender: UITextField) {

        var datePickerView:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
        sender.inputView = datePickerView
        datePickerView.addTarget(self, action: Selector("datePickerValueChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }
    func datePickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        var dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateformatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
        dateformatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
        timeField.text = dateformatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)
    }
```

The code for the second date picker:

```
@IBAction func secondCallPicker(sender: UITextField) {

        var datePickerView2:UIDatePicker = UIDatePicker()
        datePickerView2.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerMode.Time
        sender.inputView = datePickerView2
        datePickerView2.addTarget(self, action: Selector("secondPickerValueChanged:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    }

    func secondPickerValueChanged(sender: UIDatePicker) {
        var dateformatter = NSDateFormatter()
        dateformatter.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterStyle.ShortStyle
        dateformatter.dateFormat = "hh:mm"
        secondTimeLabel.text = dateformatter.stringFromDate(sender.date)

    }
```

And to dismiss the keyboard:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "DismissKeyboard")
        view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

I added this function:

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)}


    func DismissKeyboard(){
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? and how to get the date picker of the second text filed right in the first tap?